# getting to phpmyadmin on ec2

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, phpmyadmin

I have an ec2 running Amazon Linux AMI and I'm trying to hit phpmyadmin in a browser. I can SSH to MySQL and terminal says 'listening port 8888 for 127.0.0.1 port 443' but when I hit 'https://127.0.0.1:8888/phpmyadmin' in my browser, I get various errors, depending on the browser.

FF says 'The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified.' Safari says 'can't establish a secure connection.'

Inbound rules allow 443 connections.

What should I check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be an issue with your SSL certificate